# I am having problems using ternary operators with typescript

Tags: html, reactjs, typescript, forms

I am having problems using ternary operators with typescript,
please check the code to understand what I am trying to say.

```
  ` 
    const QuizQuestionContainer = ({ qa }: QuizQuestionContainerPropsType) => {
      const { question, option1, option2, option3, option4 ,checked } = qa;
     return (
        <>
          <h4>{question}</h4>
          <form>
            <input
              type="radio"
              value={option1}
              name="option"
              onClick={checkOption}
              {checked === option1 ? "defaultChecked": ""}
              
            />
      );
    };
    
    export default QuizQuestionContainer;
  `
```

I am receiving a props "qa" and I destructured the value
"checked" from it and I want the input to be checked
by default if the "checked" is equal to the option but
it is throwing an error saying
"'...' expected.ts(1005)"
and
"Spread types may only be created from object types.ts(2698)"

Comment: How about `defaultChecked={checked === option1}` instead of `{checked === option1 ? "defaultChecked": ""}`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to set the prop defaultCheck using the condition you mentioned, change to:

```
defaultChecked={checked === option1}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to define what prop name you're providing a value for!

{checked === option1 ? "defaultChecked": ""} is a valid boolean value, but you need to assign it to an `input` prop. Maybe you're looking to do `checked={option1 === "defaultChecked"}`?

This could be a result of the `checked` variable having the same name as that input prop -- might be helpful to rename the variable to `isChecked` to avoid confusion in the future.

Answer (score 0):

### I believe what you want to do here is determine if the input is checked
`checked` accepts a boolean (true = checked)

changed to this:
`checked={checked === option1}`